# Partial fraction from apart()

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I'm trying to compute the partial fraction of the following **eq** variable but I am not succeeding  on it.

```
N=1
D=1 + a*R + b*R**2
eq=N/D
```

I'am using the method **apart** as

```
apart(eq,R)
```

but, it returns the same not partial fraction, and this is not the expected result since the denominator is a second order polynomial.

What could I do for get the partial fractions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To achieve the partial fraction decomposition, in this case, it is necessary to set the flag full to True, i.e. apart(function, full=True). With this flag on the apart method will use a different algorithm to fraction decomposition that somehow is more powerful. With the flag set to True, the part method returns a not human-readable result. Nevertheless, it can be turn it into a readable result using doit().

[Here](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/polys/reference.html), in the documentation there is a better explanation.